# How to display a dialog on an already open webpage whenever new data is available to be displayed?

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell, cron

I need two things to happen periodically in the background:

1. I need to check every 5 minutes if there is a new file in a directory on the server, and if there is, I need to load data from that file into the database and then delete the file from the directory.
2. Every time I load new data into the database, I need to check if the webpage which is displaying data from the database is open in users' browsers. If it is open, I want to display a dialog telling the user to reload the webpage because new data is added in the database.

For 1, I have thought that I should create a cron job to execute a PHP script every 5 minutes. And in this PHP script, I will check if there is a file in the directory and if there is, I will load data from that file into the database, and then delete the file.

But I am confused about 2. How should I go about it? How will I inform users who have already opened the web page, that new data is available, and they should reload the web page so that new data is pulled from the database and displayed.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Comment: @Cyrus Well I can write code, I have not started coding this yet, and I am NOT asking for code. What I am asking is that, please tell me how what I am trying to do is done. I mean, just like in the second last paragraph of my question I have explained how I will solve my _first_ problem; just like that, please tell me how to solve my second problem?

Comment: Ajax, websocket, long polling, server sent event...

Comment: @frz3993 Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to the first point seems logical to me. Your second point can be handled with periodical ajax requests. You use Javascript to call a page on the server to see if any new data has been added to the database.

I think a good way to do this is to add a variable to the user's session, this variable keeps a timestamp on which the check has been done for the last time. When you use AJAX to call the script, it'll check the database whether any new record has been created since then and update the variable with the current timestamp.

The script then returns whether there are new records and with Javascript you can add a message to your page. You can even return the data if you want, so the user doesn't have to reload the page.